# fastest way to populate a 1D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have seen questions similar to this, but not one directly addressing the issue.
I have timed the following two ways of populating the array and half the time using np.zeros() is faster and half the time doing it directly is faster.
Is there a preferable way? I am quite new to using numpy arrays, and have gotten involved with the aim of speeding up my code rather without too much thought to readability.

```
import numpy as np
import time

lis = range(100000)

timer = time.time()
list1 = np.array(lis)
print 'normal array creation', time.time() - timer, 'seconds'

timer = time.time()
list2 = np.zeros(len(lis))
list2.fill(lis)
print 'zero, fill - array creation', time.time() - timer, 'seconds'
```

Thank you

Comment: The pythonic way to benchmark execution speed is using the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module.

Comment: @mac ok I will use that from now on. This is pretty much the first time/profile(cProfiler) I have needed to time my functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a list of floats `a=[x/10. for x in range(100000)]`, then you can create an array with:

```
np.array(a) # 9.92ms
np.fromiter(a, dtype=np.float) # 5.19ms
```

Your approach

```
list2 = np.zeros(len(lis))
list2.fill(lis)
```

won't work as expected. The `.fill` fills the whole array with one value.

Comment: sorry should have been more explicit, this code was just for testing the speed, it will be filled with real data when I am going to use it. (the data points will be floats)

Comment: For the `np.array` vs. `np.fromiter` I'm surprised the second is faster.  If it's an iterator numpy won't know how much memory to allocate at first.  (It must be checking if it can get a length.)  The better performance is because you're telling numpy the explicit type to use.  If you passed the dtype to `np.array` that would be faster still.

Answer (score 2):

`np.fromiter` will pre-allocate the output array if given the number of elements:

```
a = [x/10. for x in range(100000)] # 10.3ms
np.fromiter(a, dtype=np.float) # 3.33ms
np.fromiter(a, dtype=np.float, count=100000) # 3.03ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `list2` example simply doesn't work—if you inspect `list2`, you'll find that it still contains all zeroes. I find that pursuing readability is not just a good aim in and of itself. It also results in an increased likelihood of correct code.

Comment: Should have been a comment... :)

Answer (score 1):

The first list can be created faster with the `arange` numpy function:

`list3 = np.arange(100000)`

You can also find useful the `linspace` function.